# Intellij IDEA/ JSF Graphic Image doesn't render even though "library" and "name" do not report any errors. Same code works in NetBeans

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea

I have a basic JSF project with one index.xhtml containing one simple graphic image:

```
  <h:graphicImage library="image" name="usIcon.gif"/>
```

I created a directory names "resources" under the directory "web" (where index.xhtml is) and a directory named "image" in it. Then the error reported for "library="image"" went away. Then I added the file into "image" and the error reported for "name="usIcon.gif"" went away as well. When I run it though the icon doesn't render.

In NetBeans I did the same thing and the image renders properly.

Comment: Please elaborate "icon doesnt render" in developer's terms instead of enduser's terms. Is the right HTML output generated? Is the right image URL generated? Is that image URL reachable? Did it return the right response? Etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I meant was that the link is broken. IE the browser displays the default icon for images it cant find. Today I ran it again and it worked just fine so unfortunately I cant replicate it. Maybe the it was related to the GlassFish server and it sorted itself out when the server restarted.

Comment: OK, apparently just a dirty build. In the future, when something appears to be missing even though the code is in place, always first perform a full clean, rebuild, redeploy and restart to exclude a dirty build from being the cause.

Comment: Thanks, I ll keep this in mind. If i ever manage get a handle on all this :). I had never heard of the term dirty build before.